# Denying access to Calendar still allows provides calendar access to the app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying Event Kit with SwiftUI and when I tap on a button within the app, my app checks for calendar authorization and if not authorized, it shows a prompt to the user. If the user denies access to calendar, iOS 16.4 doesn't show create event view, but iOS 17.0 does.

How can I avoid iOS 17 from displaying create event view after user denies access to the calendar?

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import EventKitUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var openEventView: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button { self.openEventView = true } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.plus").font(.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.blue).padding(.trailing, 5.0)
                        Text("Add to Calendar").font(.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40.0, height: 44.0)
                .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .listRowBackground(EmptyView())
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$openEventView, content: {
                EventEditView()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct EventEditView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var eventStoreInitAfterAuth = false
    @State private var eventStore: EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
    let event: EKEvent? = nil

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<EventEditView>) -> EKEventEditViewController {
        Task {
            await checkCalendarAuthorizationStatus()
        }
        
        let eventEditViewController = EKEventEditViewController()
        eventEditViewController.eventStore = eventStore

        if let event = event {
            eventEditViewController.event = event
        }
        
        eventEditViewController.editViewDelegate = context.coordinator
        return eventEditViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: EKEventEditViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<EventEditView>) {

    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, EKEventEditViewDelegate {
        let parent: EventEditView

        init(_ parent: EventEditView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func eventEditViewController(_ controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

            if action != .canceled {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkCalendarAuthorizationStatus() async -> Bool {
        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
        switch status {
            case .notDetermined:
                return await requestAccessToCalendar()
            case .authorized, .fullAccess:
                if !eventStoreInitAfterAuth {
                    eventStore = EKEventStore()
                }
                eventStoreInitAfterAuth = true
                return true
            case .restricted, .denied:
                return false
            default:
                return false
        }
    }
    
    private func requestAccessToCalendar() async -> Bool {
        do {
            if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                let accessGranted = try await eventStore.requestFullAccessToEvents()
                return accessGranted
            } else {
                let accessGranted = try await eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event)
                return accessGranted
            }
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: To successfully run my code, you will have to add "NSCalendarsUsageDescription" description to info plist file otherwise app will crash.*

First image is from iOS 16.4 and second image is from iOS 17.0 after I deny access to Calendar access.

I would actually like to close the sheet if user denies access to calendar. What am I doing wrong in the code?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the behaviour of `EKEditEventView` has changed in iOS 17. You are able to present this view controller no matter what permission you have.  You will receive an error when the user actually tries to add the event if your app does not have calendar write access.

You will need to reactor your code so that it first requests access to the calendar and then only proceeds if it is granted.

You can use an intermediate view to replace Apple's functionality with your own.

```
import SwiftUI

import Foundation
import EventKitUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var openEventView: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Button { self.openEventView = true } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "calendar.badge.plus").font(.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.blue).padding(.trailing, 5.0)
                        Text("Add to Calendar").font(.body.bold()).foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                }
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40.0, height: 44.0)
                .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.5))
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
                .listRowBackground(EmptyView())
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$openEventView, content: {
                EventAddView(showView: $openEventView)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct EventAddView: View  {
    @State var access = EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined
    @Binding  var showView: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch access {
            case .notDetermined:
                ProgressView()
            case .restricted, .denied:
                Text("Calendar access not provided.")
                
                Button(action: {
                    if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
                        // Ask the system to open that URL.
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Provide access in settings")
                }
            case .fullAccess, .writeOnly, .authorized:
                EventEditView()
            @unknown default:
                Text("Unknown case")
            }
        }.task {
            self.access = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
            if await self.requestAccessToCalendar() {
                self.access = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    private func requestAccessToCalendar() async -> Bool {
        let eventStore = EKEventStore()
        do {
            if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
                let accessGranted = try await eventStore.requestFullAccessToEvents()
                return accessGranted
            } else {
                let accessGranted = try await eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event)
                return accessGranted
            }
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}

struct EventEditView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var eventStoreInitAfterAuth = false
    @State private var eventStore: EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
    let event: EKEvent? = nil

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<EventEditView>) -> EKEventEditViewController {
        let eventEditViewController = EKEventEditViewController()
        eventEditViewController.eventStore = eventStore

        if let event = event {
            eventEditViewController.event = event
        }
        
        eventEditViewController.editViewDelegate = context.coordinator
        return eventEditViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: EKEventEditViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<EventEditView>) {

    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, EKEventEditViewDelegate {
        let parent: EventEditView

        init(_ parent: EventEditView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func eventEditViewController(_ controller: EKEventEditViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventEditViewAction) {
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

            if action != .canceled {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is also worth noting that `.authorized` is a [deprecated Value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekauthorizationstatus/1451886-authorized) in iOS 17.

If your app needs to confirm that it can read events then you should check for `.fullAccess` on iOS 17.

Alternatively if you only need to create events then you should `requestWriteOnlyAccessToEvents` and check for `.writeOnly`

Comment: Good to know. Xcode never gave me a warning on that and I wasn't aware. Thanks for sharing! I added "fullAccess" to switch in 'checkCalendarAuthorizationStatus", but the issue still remains i.e. even after I select "Don't Allow" calendar access, I do have access to create event.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything with the result of `checkCalendarAuthorizationStatus`.  It shows the view regardless

Comment: Intermediate view sounds like a good idea. I would be having some more code to populate the contents on event view and also to cancel any existing events added by my app. Intermediate view would help me modularize the code better and also helps solving the issue. Thanks!

Comment: One question related to this. Have you tried adding just "NSCalendarsFullAccessUsageDescription" to your info plist, executing the app and then going to Settings -> App Settings -> Calendar permissions specific to your app. Do you still see all 3 options - None, Add Events only and Full access?

I am seeing 3 options even if I wish to have full access permission. If iOS is still showing 3 permissions than that means I would need to handle "writeOnly" as well incase if user manually swiches to it from app settings.

Comment: Yes. The user can select "write only". Your app should handle this appropriately; by disabling features that require calendar read and/or promoting the user to grant access in settings

Comment: Thanks for checking, @Paulw11! Just wanted to make sure if others are also seeing "Add Events Only" in app settings. I will handle that setting in my app. Thanks again!

Comment: Have you by any chance worked on opening the event in edit mode on iOS 17? Similar to this, I tried creating a view using EKEventViewController, which works and the event details does get displayed for existing event on the calendar, but edit button is missing in iOS 17. Works fine in iOS 16.

Comment: I have posted a question related to editing event in here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78212946/edit-button-not-showing-up-on-edit-event-view-using-ekeventviewcontroller