# Edit button not showing up on edit event view using EKEventViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI app and have created a bridge/coordinator to open an event details view. This view usually has "Edit" button to allow editing the event, but I am not seeing it when I run the code below in iOS 17. It works in iOS 16.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import EventKitUI

struct EKView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var existingEvent: EKEvent

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<EKView>) -> EKEventViewController {
        let eventViewController = EKEventViewController()
        eventViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        eventViewController.event = existingEvent
        eventViewController.allowsCalendarPreview = true
        eventViewController.allowsEditing = true
        return eventViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: EKEventViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<EKView>) {

    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, EKEventViewDelegate {
        let parent: EKView

        init(_ parent: EKView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func eventViewController(_ controller: EKEventViewController, didCompleteWith action: EKEventViewAction) {
            if action == .deleted {

            }
            
            if action == .done {

            }

            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone here tried opening existing event using "EKEventViewController" on iOS 17. Does edit button work for you? Or how do I make edit button visible to edit/delete the event?

Comment: Maybe not related but `Coordinator(self)` is a mistake because self is a value not a reference so when you call dismiss it'll be some old value not the latest. You could fix it by setting it again in `updateUIViewController` but usually you would set a closure to do it.